# Group records in a MYSQL query - Do not display every result

Tags: mysql, group-by, grouping

If an SQL query gives me the following results how can I get it to group results.  I.E. if there are two instances of the same RecordID, but with different CourseID's, to not echo both row's but only echo one QuestionID and display the two CourseID's in brackets?

[image: SQL Query result]

It is MYSQL and PHP.

Any help is appreciated.
Daniel

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT QuestionID,
       TopicID,
       CONCAT('(',GROUP_CONCAT(CourseID ORDER BY CourseID),')'),
       UserID
FROM   yourTable
WHERE  UserID = 2
```

See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1436b/8).

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the column you want to ignore and then use distinct

Comment: So if I use SELECT DISTINCT, this would work?  Also, I don't want to ignore TopicID if possible as that is echoed also?

Comment: Select Distinct will remove repeated lines (comparing all the columns).